# JavaScript - CTRL KeyCode of 17 does not work?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an application that needs to detect whether or not the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key was pressed.

My code is as follows:

```
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 13 || event.keyCode != 38 || event.keyCode != 40 || event.keyCode != 17)
        {
            // execute this
        }
```

(The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is the last keycode in that if statement.)

After searching the internet it says to use 17 as the keycode, but it is still EXECUTING "// Execute this" if i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>. 
It's not supposed to execute it.

All other keys work properly in the if statement, and I'm using Chrome 31 stable/official.

I am also using 'keydown' and not 'keypress' as you can see.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: `CTRL` is a modifier key.  Check for `event.ctrlKey` (a boolean value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This condition

```
event.keyCode != 13 || event.keyCode != 38 || event.keyCode != 40 || event.keyCode != 17
```

will *always* be true. This can be proven with two cases.

- If `event.keyCode` is `13`, then `event.keyCode != 38` will cause the expression to return `true` because `13 != 38`.
- If `event.keyCode` is not `13`, then the condition `event.keyCode != 13` will cause the expression to return `true.`

I believe that **you are wanting to use the `&&` operator** instead of the `||` operator.

Also, instead of checking `event.keyCode !== 17`, I think it is more readable to use `!event.ctrlKey` because it tells the reader of the code that you are checking about the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key, whereas you have to look up `17` in a keycode table in order to find out what it means.

(As an aside, [the `!==` and `===` operators are preferred in the Javascript community over the `!=` and `==` operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons).)

Comment: **+1** You deserved the checkmark, I didn't type quick enough ;)

Comment: @ManofSnow Thanks) I upvoted yours also, since it was just as correct as mine and included a demo.

Comment: And the reason the other keys worked was because of other code I had.

Answer (score 2):

**1** Change the or operator to an and operator (&&)

**2** Fix your code errors, missing a semicolon and close parentheses

Your final code should look like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode != 13 && event.keyCode != 38 && event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 17) {
        alert(event.keyCode);
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZD88X/)

Comment: Thank you very much I did mean to use &&! And I also accidentally cut off my code in here but I did finish the brackets in my code!